# Why isn't my app using manifest.json when I "Add to Homescreen"?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

So I have a Create React App on the go, and have been using it on my device (LG G7) adding it to the homescreen.

But then I tried changing the colors and the name, and they won't take no matter what I do it seems.

I'm hosting the app on Firebase, and have repeatedly rebuilt and redeployed to Firebase and keep cleaning out the old app, and re add to homescreen.

Here's the manifest.json:

```json
{
  "short_name": "test",
  "name": "test2",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#dd0000",
  "background_color": "#0000aa"
}
```

Any insight or thoughts would be great!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Go to chrome on your pc and check if the manifest has updated or not in your deployed app

Comment: Yeah, I checked the site on desktop and it's there, live. But still the "app" is showing "Create React App" and "React App" in spots. Which is wild, because NOWHERE in my code base is there those words. Could it be a service worker issue? (I don't have one)

Comment: Where is it showing those words, mention exactly. Is it like in the meta description

Comment: Thanks for your help man, but this suddenly just is working. (Assuming my phone was caching the manifest or something)

Comment: Ohh fine, anyways glad to help

Answer (score 0):

This is finally working. I just had to keep deleting it off my homescreen and refreshing in the browser before it finally clicked!